# Is it the correct neural network reprsentation

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics

I am having the following problem. [image]

Note that the area for class $B$ stretches to the innity. We consider as an elementary computation the threshold neuron
whose relation between inputs $\{z_i\}$ and output $z_j$ is given by
[image]

In a similar way the XOR problem was solved in the slides, design at hand a neural network that takes x1 and x2 as
input and produces the output \1" if the input belong to class A, and \0" if the input belongs to class B. Draw the
neural network model and write down its corresponding weight and bias parameters.

So I wrote neural network as below.

$Just\ wondering\ is\ it\ correct\ or\ not\ because\ for\ weights\ in\ second\ layer\ I\ am\ assigning\ 1.$

$  Please\ tell\ me\ is\ it\ correct\ or\ not\ and\ can\ I\ use\ absolute\ value\ of\ x_i$

[image]

Comment: Your problem seems simpler than the XOR problem. You have two conditionals: $C_{1}=|x_{1}|<1$ and $C_{2}=|x_{2}|<1$. Then the classification becomes $A$ if $C_{1}$ *AND* $C_{2}$, otherwise $B$.